# Split a numpy array based on a given condition

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How to split a sorted numpy array, e.g., `arr=([5,6,28,29,32,33,87,88,95])` into sub-arrays such that the following two conditions are always met:

(1) The difference between the first and the last elements of a sub-array is less than 10.

(2) And, the difference between the last element of a sub-array and the first element of the next sub-array is more than 20.

In the `arr` above, expected list is `split_arr=[([5,6]),([28,29,32,33]),([87,88,95])]`.

Comment: Just iterate over the array and check the conditions on each step. You'd need to keep track of your first element of each slice and update it once you found a new boundary.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a better way..!

Comment: can you share your coding attempt?

Comment: I think your two conditions have some conflicts: consider this input: arr = [5, 6, 16, 28, 29, 32, 33, 87, 88, 95], I just put a 16 between 6 and 28; how would you want the result looks like? [[5, 6], [16], [28, 29, 32, 33], [87, 88, 95]] is clearly not right, due to it doesn't fit condition 2. Seems that here's no place for 16 in any subarray.

Comment: Looks like a corner case.. what if condition (2) is waived off @MenglongLi

Comment: @Peedaruos , I have put an answer based on NumPy that works on your example well and will be modified based on your need after your clarifications. You must clarify as *Menglong* mentioned. What should it shows if the array be as the aforementioned array? Clarify the problem if you need further help.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said, your two conditions have conflicts if arr looks like: [5, 6, 16, 28, 29, 32, 33, 87, 88, 95], and there is no place for the num **16**, so the following codes are just under condition 1, waived off condition2:

```
arr = [5, 6, 28, 29, 32, 33, 87, 88, 95]

results = []

idx = 0

sub_arr = list()

while idx <= len(arr) - 1:
    if not sub_arr:
        sub_arr.append(arr[idx])
    else:
        if arr[idx] - sub_arr[0] < 10:
            sub_arr.append(arr[idx])
        else:
            results.append(sub_arr)
            sub_arr = list()
            sub_arr.append(arr[idx])
    idx += 1

if sub_arr:
    results.append(sub_arr)

print(results)
```

Output:

```
[[5, 6], [28, 29, 32, 33], [87, 88, 95]]
```

Comment: Thanks, can there be pythonic (numpy) way to do this w/o having to do all this.. keeping performance issue in mind for large chunks.. say 10^7 points in the array and it takes lot of time!

Comment: The Big O for this is O(n), you can see  that the array is only looped once.

Comment: I can accept it if there is no other workaround at all

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using just NumPy by starting from condition 2 and then condition 1:

```
diff1 = np.diff(arr, prepend=arr[0]-21, append=arr[-1]+21)  # [21  1 22  1  3  1 54  1  7 21]
ind = np.where(diff1 > 20)[0]             # [0 2 6 9]
start = ind[:-1]                          # [0 2 6]
end = ind[1:] - 1                         # [1 5 8]
cond1 = (arr[end] - arr[start]) < 10      # [True True True]
result = np.split(arr, start[cond1][1:])  # [array([5, 6]), array([28, 29, 32, 33]), array([87, 88, 95])]
```